# closures: expected u32 found type parameter

Tags: function, generics, rust, closures, traits

The problem is that my generic type `T` only accepts arguments from `u32` and in this case I am trying to pass a generic value that I store in `U`.

Is there a way to cast generics to a specific type? What can I do to solve the problem?

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Cacher<T, U> where T: Fn(u32) -> u32 {
    calcular:T,
    valor:Option<U>,
}
impl<T, U> Cacher<T, U> where T: Fn(u32) -> u32 {
    fn nuevo(calcular:T, valor:U) -> Cacher<T, U> {
        Cacher{
            calcular,
            valor:None,
        }
    }
    fn valor(&mut self, arg:U) -> u32 {
        match self.valor {
            Some(v) => v,
            None => {
                let v = (self.calcular)(arg);
                self.valor = Some(arg);
                v
            }
        }
    }
}

fn generar(intensidad:u32){
    let mut resultado = Cacher::nuevo(|num| {
        println!("Trabajando");
        num
    },None);

    let res_a = resultado.valor(Some(4));
}

fn main() {
    generar(3);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either remove the generic type parameter `U` from your implementation and only use `u32`s:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Cacher<T>
    where T: Fn(u32) -> u32 
{
    calcular: T,
    valor: Option<u32>,
}

impl<T> Cacher<T>
    where T: Fn(u32) -> u32
{
    fn nuevo(calcular: T) -> Cacher<T> {
        Cacher {
            calcular,
            valor: None,
        }
    }

    fn valor(&mut self, arg: u32) -> u32 {
        match self.valor {
            Some(v) => v,
            None => {
                let v = (self.calcular)(arg);
                self.valor = Some(arg);
                v
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut resultado = Cacher::nuevo(|num| {
        println!("Trabajando");
        num
    });

    // "Trabajando" only printed once
    // hence we know we got a cache hit
    let res_a = resultado.valor(4);
    let res_a = resultado.valor(4);
    

    println!("{:?}", res_a);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ba992c3524014b0378d3cb5ce616c867)

*Or* make your implementation fully-generic:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Cacher<T, U>
    where T: Fn(U) -> U, U: Copy
{
    calcular: T,
    valor: Option<U>,
}

impl<T, U> Cacher<T, U>
    where T: Fn(U) -> U, U: Copy
{
    fn nuevo(calcular: T) -> Cacher<T, U> {
        Cacher {
            calcular,
            valor: None,
        }
    }

    fn valor(&mut self, arg: U) -> U {
        match self.valor {
            Some(v) => v,
            None => {
                let v = (self.calcular)(arg);
                self.valor = Some(arg);
                v
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut resultado = Cacher::nuevo(|num| {
        println!("Trabajando");
        num
    });

    // "Trabajando" only printed once
    // hence we know we got a cache hit
    let res_a = resultado.valor(4);
    let res_a = resultado.valor(4);
    

    println!("{:?}", res_a);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5388ac54775da29545a1027b1476658a)

The above implementation will work for any `U` that implements `Copy`, so that includes all number primitives, e.g. `u8`, `u16`, etc.